# Get Sql Query LoggerAbstract in Observer M2

Tags: event-observer

How to get Sql Query LoggerAbstract to find bind value of last column update.
I try to use LoggerAbstract Code to my Observer, but I just got like this.

```
## 7435 ## a ** TIME: 0.1047
```

Not like i want.

```
## 2018-02-06 06:41:10    
## 7816 ## QUERY
SQL: SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` FROM 
`catalog_product_entity` WHERE (sku = :value)
BIND: array (
   ':value' => 'PALELU',
)
AFF: 0
TIME: 0.0245
```

I want to get some BIND value  'PALELU'.

Here is my Observer Code.

**Getstats (from LoggerAbstract)**

```
public function getStats($type, $sql, $bind = [], $result = null)
{
    $sbind = var_export($bind, true);
    $holiShit = $sbind[0];
    //$getBind = $bind->value;
    $message = '## ' . getmypid() . ' ## ' . $holiShit . ' ** ';
    $nl   = "\n";
    $time = sprintf('%.4f', microtime(false));

    if (!$this->logAllQueries && $time < $this->logQueryTime) {
        return '';
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case self::TYPE_CONNECT:
            $message .= 'CONNECT' . $nl;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_TRANSACTION:
            $message .= 'TRANSACTION ' . $sql . $nl;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_QUERY:
            $message .= 'QUERY' . $nl;
            $message .= 'SQL: ' . $sql . $nl;
            if ($bind) {
                $message .= 'BIND: ' . var_export($bind, true) . $nl;
            }
            if ($result instanceof \Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo) {
                $message .= 'AFF: ' . $result->rowCount() . $nl;
            }
            break;
    }
    $message .= 'TIME: ' . $time . $nl;


    $message .= $nl;

    return $message;
}
```

**Execute**

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
   $fuckthis = $this->getStats($bind = [],$result = null);
   $options = array(
        "email" => $userEmail,
        "information"   => $fuckthis
    );

    $getLog = json_encode($options);
    $this->_customLoggerHelper
            ->log(
                $getLog
            );
 }
```

I don't know how to get BIND value like SqlQuery Log with di.xml.

Thank's in Advance